# How to get and display data from mongodb using nodejs after passing the parameter in the URL?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, parameters

After passing the parameter in the URL, I just want to display the data from Mongodb when the user enters the URL with the parameter.

For example, if the URL is "http://www.example.com/product/1" data that belongs to id value "1" should be retrieved and displayed in the frontend.

I have written code for displaying the data based on the id but it is not showing the result as it has some errors which I am not able to find out.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.get('/product/:id', (req, res) => {
    var data = [
        {
            id: 1,

        },
        {
            id: 2,

        }
    ]
    data.forEach((product) => {

        if (product.id == req.params.id) {


            MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {

                if (err) throw err;
                var dbo = db.db('product')
                var cursor = dbo.collection('details').find();
                cursor.forEach((doc, err) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    data.push('doc');
                }, () => {
                    db.close();

                });
            });
            return true;

        }

    })
    res.render('productdetails',{title:"Product Details", product: data});

});
```

And the html section is

```
<h3><%= data.producttitle %></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem number 1 - Find method is and async method, that means that you have to wait for the result (either using wait or then)

Problem number 2 - you are pushing a string to the data array instead of the data itself.
You also can avoid the use of another array

Problem number 3 - you did not specified any filter to the find

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
const ejs = require('ejs');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())


app.get('/product/:id', (req, res) => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, db) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var dbo = db.db('product')
    dbo.collection('details').find({id : id}).toArray().then(products => {
    res.render('productdetails',{title:"Product Details", product: products[0]});}).catch(err => {throw err;});
});
```